# Convert Node JS HMAC to C#

Tags: c#, node.js, hmac

I have been attempting to convert an HMAC middleware code snip to C#. The Node JS code is very simple.

```
 const hash = crypto
.createHmac('sha256', 'SHA-Key')
.update(JSON.stringify(req.body))
.digest('hex');

if (hash === req.header('X-HMAC-Sha-256')) {
    next();
} else {
    res.send(401, 'Not authorized.');
}
```

My C# code

```
    public string CalculateSHA256Hash(byte[] key, string requestContent, string senderHash)
    {   
        string hexHash = "";
        // Initialize the keyed hash object.
        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
        {
            byte[] requestByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestContent);

            // Create a FileStream for the source file.
            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(requestByteArray))
            {
                // Read in the storedHash.
                inStream.Read(requestByteArray, 0, requestByteArray.Length);
                // Compute the hash of the remaining contents of the file.
                // The stream is properly positioned at the beginning of the content,
                // immediately after the stored hash value.
                byte[] computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(inStream);
                hexHash = Convert.ToHexString(computedHash);
            }
        }

        return hexHash;
     }
```

When I run the code I never get the same result as the senders HMAC hash. Is it something to do with the Digest Hex in node.js vs my convert toHexString?

Comment: Are you making a distinction between _request body_ (which does `JSON.stringify(req.body)`) vs just _request content_? ...which I can't tell what it is, but maybe it's accidentally just the request body not JSON.stringified the same way node.js did it? Or maybe the request body is already stringified but not byte for byte identical (like maybe it has different line endings or different spacing or indentation)

Comment: In my C# code, the parameter requestContent is the body of the request which is a JSON string.

Comment: ...but in your node.js it looks like your original request JSON string is being parsed into `req.body` (presumably by middleware such as `app.use(express.json())`), then you are stringifying it again with `JSON.stringify(req.body)`  And that may result in a binary difference in the string representation of your JSON such as indentation, spacing, newlines, etc.   Can you examine the output of `JSON.stringify(req.body)` and compare it to the original request?

Comment: You're so correct Wyck

Answer (score 1):

So I needed to dig into exactly what the node.js code was accomplishing for this HMAC hash. I found that once I understood what the json.stringify() was doing this became trivial to implement.

```
    public string CalculateSHA256Hash(byte[] key, string requestContent)
    {
        string hexHash = "";
        try
        {
            // Initialize the keyed hash object.
            using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
            {
                byte[] requestByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestContent);

                // Create a FileStream for the source request body.
                using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(requestByteArray))
                {
                    byte[] computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(inStream);
                    hexHash = Convert.ToHexString(computedHash).ToLower();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return hexHash;
    }
```

I used the following to get the equivalent of json.stringify()

```
     //Stringify
     strBody = strBody.Replace(" ", "");
     strBody = strBody.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```